# Accessing Azure Synapse Analytics from Node.js Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, tedious

I am trying to access an Azure Synapse SQL Pool out of a Node.js Function. I took this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/a-node-function-app-to-get-json-results-from-azure-synapse-analytics-e671dd6ae827) as a foundation and switch the authentication method to 'azure-active-directory-msi-app-service'.

If I run the function I can see the queryText context.log in the Function cmd but unfortunately nothing else happens. It runs without any kind of output.

I cant see any other context.log or get any response from the function.

````
const Request = require('tedious').Request;
const TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
const test = require('lodash')

module.exports = function (context, req) {
   //get the Query Parameter

   // Create connection to database
   const config = {
     authentication: {
         type: "azure-active-directory-msi-app-service"
     },
     server: "database.sql.azuresynapse.net", 
     options: {
         database: "database", 
         encrypt: true,
         port: 1433
     }
   };

   const connection = new Connection(config);

   // Create array to store the query results
   let result = [];
   let rowData = {};

   // req.query.color will be passed as a query variable in the URL
   //const payload = [req.query.color];

   // Create query to execute against the database
   const queryText = "SELECT TOP (10) [id],[column1],[column2] FROM [dbo].[Table]";
   context.log(queryText);
   
   // Create Request object
   request = new Request(queryText, function(err) {
       context.log("Request")
       if (err) {
           // Error in executing query
           context.log.error(err);
           context.res.status = 500;
           context.res.body = "Error executing the query";
       } else {
           context.res = {
               status: 200,
               isRaw: true,
               body: result,
               headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
               }
           }
       }
       context.done();
   });

   // Manipulate the results and create JSON
   request.on('row', function(columns) {
       rowData = {};
       columns.forEach(function(column) {
           // IMPORTANT: Change the conversion logic here to adjust JSON format
           rowData[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
       });
       result.push(rowData);
   });

   connection.on('connect', function(err) {
       if (err) {
           // Error in connecting
           context.log.error(err);
           context.res.status = 500;
           context.res.body = "Error connecting to Azure Synapase";
           context.done();
       } else {
           // Connection succeeded
           connection.execSql(request);
       }
   });
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
const Request = require('tedious').Request;
const TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

const config = {
    server: "SQL pool endpoint goes here",
    authentication: {
        type: "azure-active-directory-msi-app-service"
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        database: "pool name goes here",
        port: 1433
    }
}
var connection = new Connection(config);
```

This assumes that you appropriately assigned managed identities as external users in the SQL pool. I also have a PR for this change which you can track [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/73247)